# Login em área restrita

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho um site com um form de login dentro de uma div, que clicada abre modal.

```
<a href='#' id='login-link'>Login</a>
```

Tenho algumas áreas restritas no site, e gostaria de exibir o form de login no caso do usuário não estar logado, porém não estou conseguindo.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
    //EXIBIR A DIV PARA LOGIN 
}
```

JS

```
$("#login-link").click(function(){
   $("#login-form").fadeIn(300);
   document.form1.loading.style.visibility = "hidden";
   $("#background-on-popup").css("opacity", "0.7");
   $("#background-on-popup").fadeIn(300);
   document.getElementById("username").value = "";
   document.getElementById("password").value = "";
   $("#username").focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

O código ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
<? if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])): ?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#login-link").click(function(){
   $("#login-form").fadeIn(300);
   document.form1.loading.style.visibility = "hidden";
   $("#background-on-popup").css("opacity", "0.7");
   $("#background-on-popup").fadeIn(300);
   document.getElementById("username").value = "";
   document.getElementById("password").value = "";
   $("#username").focus();
}); 
});
</script>
<? endif; ?>
```